# ¿Como saber si un archivo tiene datos en php?

Tags: php

Me gustaría saber cual es la forma correcta de saber cuando un archivo tiene información dentro de si.

Código actual:

```
$myfile = fopen("app/vista/html5/encabezado/encabezado.html", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
if ($myfile == false) {
  echo "No tiene nada";
} else {
  echo "Tiene algo";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Lo único que busco es saber si tiene por lo menos un carácter o una línea como contenido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto se puede lograr de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
 $archivo = "url o direccion del archivo";
 if(filesize($archivo) > 0){
  echo "El archivo tiene contenido";

 } else {
  echo "El archivo esta vacio";
 }
?>
```

`filesize` devuelve el tamaño del fichero en bytes, o FALSE (y genera un error de nivel E_WARNING) en caso de que se produzca un error.

Si el archivo contiene datos debe tener un tamaño diferente de 0 bytes, en el caso de un documento de texto plano.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes valerte de la función [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filesize.php). La misma determina el tamaño del archivo, sin tener que leerlo completamente.

He aquí un código usando operador ternario para determinar si el archivo está vacío o no.

Se puede usar en combinación con [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php) para evitar un Warning en el error_log, cuando el archivo no exista:

**EDIT: Hay que negar las comprobaciones para que funcione. Se me había escapado**

```
$nombre_fichero = 'archivo.txt';
$vacio=(!file_exists($nombre_fichero) || !filesize($nombre_fichero)) ? FALSE : TRUE;

/*Prueba de la variable*/
var_dump($vacio);
```

Cuando esté vacío, el valor de la variable será:

```
bool(false)
```

Y cuando tenga datos:

```
bool(true)
```

La ventaja de este método es que verificará también si el archivo existe o no. Cuando no exista, el valor será siempre `false`.

Comment: Pero, si  el archivo existe pero contiene 0 bytes devolveria true.

Comment: Lo he editado @Sacha, hay que cambiar el ternario. Ahora funciona bien.

Comment: Buenisimo ;D Puede ser que el operador tenario sea algo confuso, no hace falta que la edites mas pero te planteo la siguiente expresion `$vacio = file_exists($nombre_fichero) and (filesize($nombre_fichero) > 0)` muchas gracias

Comment: @Sacha mi idea era simplificar: haciendo ambas cosas en una sola evaluación y evitando que nuestro log de errores se llene de advertencias `PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed `. Cuando te has acostumbrado a usar los ternarios, el código no resulta tan confuso. Gracias por tu propuesta, la cual también es válida.